# Where I went wrong in $O(GL_2(\mathbb Z_3))=48?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In course of showing $O(GL_2(\mathbb Z_3))=48$ I couldn't find where I went wrong. Please help me !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You counted the case "2 of $a,b,c,d$ are 0" incorrectly.  You seem to have $2 \cdot (2+2) = 8$ for that case, but the correct count is 16: there are four ways to choose which two entries are zero -- they have to be adjacent entries in the matrix, and then there are four ways to choose the nonzero values for the other two entries.  This accounts for the 8 extra matrices in your count.

Comment: It would probably be courteous to give an upvote as well as an accept here.

Answer (score 3):

Your question has already been answered, but here is a less error-prone way to do it.

For the first column, we may choose any nonzero vector. There are $3\cdot 3 -1=8$ of these. For the second column, we may choose any nonzero vector not in the span of the first vector. There are $3\cdot 3 - 3=6$ of these. We get a final tally of $8\cdot 6 =48.$